# Is there a verbose/colored mode for `lein test` / `clojure.test`?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, clojure.test

The default output from `clojure.test` via `lein test` is pretty underwhelming:

```
Ran 1 tests containing 1 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

I guess maybe Clojure people are minimalists, but in every other language I've used test runners use red/green colors to indicate failing/passing tests at a glance, and generally come with a verbose mode I can use to see each test being run.

It looks like possibly I can do this through the [`do-report` method in `clojure.test`](https://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.test-api.html#clojure.test/do-report). But is there a plugin or option or something that does this already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[kaocha](https://github.com/lambdaisland/kaocha) and [eftest](https://github.com/weavejester/eftest) can both be used with `lein test` and produce colourful test output.